# Migrating RAID 1 to new size drives

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, raid

We have six 3TB drives in a RAID 1 array on an Ubuntu machine. One of the drives failed (actually the second time this has happened) so I want to replace it, but I am thinking of trying to update all six drives to 4TB as I do it.

I know that if I mix and match, the smallest drive will be the limiting factor. But if I gradually swap out all the 3TB drives (so the new 4TB drives get incorporated into the array), then **once they are all changed will I have six x 4TB usable**?

Comment: I've just read you're using Ubuntu (mdadm). http://www.subvs.co.uk/expand_raid1_array_ubuntu There are a number of Ubuntu tutorials to grow a RAID1 using mdadm. As you swap the disks and partition the new ones you add them. Once all the disks have been swapped (gradually to allow resync) you can then grow the partition. I thought you were using a hardware RAID, sorry!

Comment: Chris, if you want to put that as an answer I'll accept.